# Angular 2 issue: typings: command not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular, typescript-typings

So this might come off as a really basic question but it has been bugging me for days now and haven't actually found a solution.

I'm installing typings from the command line with npm and it appears to run well but then I type any typing command and it says that the command doesn't exist!

It goes something like:

```
    Kevyns-MacBook-Pro:~ kevynquiros$ sudo npm install typings --global
Password:
/Users/kevynquiros/npm/bin/typings -> /Users/kevynquiros/npm/lib/node_modules/typings/dist/bin.js
typings@1.0.4 /Users/kevynquiros/npm/lib/node_modules/typings
├── listify@1.0.0
├── xtend@4.0.1
├── wordwrap@1.0.0
├── archy@1.0.0
├── minimist@1.2.0
├── any-promise@1.3.0
├── bluebird@3.4.0
├── chalk@1.1.3 (supports-color@2.0.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@2.2.1, has-ansi@2.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1)
├── columnify@1.5.4 (strip-ansi@3.0.1, wcwidth@1.0.1)
├── update-notifier@0.7.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, xdg-basedir@2.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, ansi-align@1.0.0, boxen@0.5.1, configstore@2.0.0, latest-version@2.0.0)
└── typings-core@1.0.1 (array-uniq@1.0.2, thenify@3.2.0, zip-object@0.1.0, popsicle-status@2.0.0, graceful-fs@4.1.4, popsicle-retry@3.1.0, throat@2.0.2, lockfile@1.0.1, promise-finally@2.2.0, string-template@1.0.0, strip-bom@2.0.0, sort-keys@1.1.2, make-error-cause@1.1.0, debug@2.2.0, has@1.0.1, rc@1.1.6, object.pick@1.1.2, configstore@2.0.0, parse-json@2.2.0, invariant@2.2.1, detect-indent@4.0.0, mkdirp@0.5.1, touch@1.0.0, is-absolute@0.2.5, popsicle-proxy-agent@2.0.1, rimraf@2.5.2, typescript@1.8.7, popsicle@6.2.0)
```

And then this is what happens:

```
Kevyns-MacBook-Pro:~ kevynquiros$ typings search tape
-bash: typings: command not found
```

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the cmd output in your question, the `typings` package is installed in `/Users/kevynquiros/npm/bin/typings`. You need to add that folder to your `PATH`.

One way to do it is:

- Create "or edit" the file `/Users/kevynquiros/.bash_profile`
- In that file, add a line:

  `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/kevynquiros/npm/bin/`
- close and re-open `terminal` and it should work.

Comment: Had the same issue - this fixed it for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hey thank you a lot! Gonna try it an see if it works!

Comment: glad to hear that @KevynQuiros, If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it by clicking on the check mark just below the vote count. And welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Totally, there it is. Thank you again and greetings from Costa Rica!

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `npm install typings -g`